# TickCount reset event?

Tags: c#, .net

The MSDN documentation describes the Environment.TickCount Property as the number of milliseconds since the **system** started.  However, the return value is descibed as the number of milliseconds since the **computer** was started.

Which one is it?

BTW, I consider a system restart as a restart without powering off the computer while I consider a computer restart as both a shutdown and power reset.

Thank you for your response

Comment: You may be reading a little too much into this. They're most likely the same event.

Comment: That said, I'd be interested if anyone knows what happens when a laptop sleeps / hibernates.

Comment: @ChrisShain Pretty easy to test, and I'd bet they're still identical.

Comment: @Yuck I'm sure.  I'm also too lazy to try at the moment :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows has no idea the difference between a reset and a shutdown.

`Environment.TickCount` property increments only when the operating system is running; it pauses when the computer goes into certain power-saving modes, such as standby or hibernation. The TickCount property is unrelated to the computer's clock setting.